# Get status of upload progress while uploading files to S3 using AWS Amplify

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am uploading a file through angular to S3 using `aws-amplify` sdk and i want to see how much file has been uploaded to the bucket.

```
Storage.put(id, name)
    .then (result => console.log(result))
    .catch(err => console.log(err)).on('httpUploadProgress', function(progress) {
    // Here you can use `this.body` to determine which file this particular
    // event is related to and use that info to calculate overall progress.
});
```

This does not work and i cannot seem to find a solution for it.

Answer (score 3):

Amplify docs include this now - https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage#put

Answer (score 2):

Upload progress is possible to get for the Storage API (aws-amplify).
But it is still not documented in official [doc](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/storage).

Try this

```
Storage.put(id, name, {
  progressCallback(progress) {
    console.log(`Uploaded percentage: ${progress.loaded}/${progress.total}`);
  },
});
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and answering my problem but i cannot use `aws-sdk` in my project as i am using `amplify` . So i was looking for a solution with amplify library plus i am using Cognito Pool as authentication.

Comment: @harsh please explain your question properly